# Username conflicts on a central printer queue

Tags: users, printing, cups

We have just switched to a centralized print queue. The printer is setup with

```
lpadmin -p SPScolour -E -D "Sustainable Print Colour" -v lpd://xxx.yyy.com/colour
```

The IT people are saying my local username must match my central username. Of course the IT people are not that organized and I have a number of "central" usernames. Is there a way to specify the print queue username through an environment variable or some other trick?

I can work around the username constraint by using `lp -U mycentralusername -d SPSColour foo.txt`. This isn't a complete solution since not all GUIs give you the option of specifying the print command. If I am willing to install a different printer for each user I can do

```
lpadmin -p SPScolour -E -D "Sustainable Print Colour" -v lpd://mycentralusername@xxx.yyy.com/colour
```

I have had no luck with setting lpoptions. I have tried

```
lpoptions -d SPScolour -o username=myusername
lp -d SPSColour foo.txt
```

which does not print. It looks like `lpoptions` takes a `-U` flag, but I cannot figure out how to use it.

```
lpoptions -U myusername -d SPSColour
```

gives me an error.

Comment: Have you tried `lpoptions -U myusername -d SPSColour  -o username=myusername`? I think the `-U` flag if for `lpoptions` itself and the option `username=myusername` is used lated when you call `lp`.

Comment: @lgeorget I have tried `lpoptions -U myusername -d SPSColour -o username=myusername` and I get the same error. I cannot manage to use `lpoptions` with the `-U` flag. Further, `lp -o username=myusername -d SPSColour foo.txt` doesn't work. I am not sure username is really an "options".

Answer (score 1):

If your printer was setup with `lpadmin`, you should be able to get and set its options with `lpoptions`. There is a file called `~/.cups/lpoptions` for each user (you can create it if it doesn't exist), and another called `/etc/cups/lpoptions` for system-wide settings. If you're able to change your settings with the `lpoptions` command, then you can make the settings persistent in those configuration files.

Have a look at `man 1 lpoptions` and give it a try.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. `lpoptions` seems like the right way to go, but I cannot get it to work. I edited the question to include what I have tried.